# change menu float when site gets narrow (responsive)

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a site at www. structuredata. com

when the site is on a desktop it looks great.  However when it starts to get narrow, the red 'register' button starts to overlap the menu,
I'd like to make a media query in my css that will force the button to drop down below the navigation when viewed on smaller screens.  How would I do that?

the header is setup as

```
<div id="header_main">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="inner-container">
      <strong class="logo"></strong>
      <nav class="main_menu"></nav>
      <div id="text-8" class="widget"> BUTTON IS HERE </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried setting my .header_main.widget

to a display:block and inline-block but neither worked.  I tried clear:both on it as well.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries can be tricky, you can read a lot about them [here(w3c)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and [here(mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

In your case the media query will look something like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    #header_main .container .inner-container .widget {
        /*Styles go here*/
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation bar and your button are on a different z-index, so that's going to be tricky. That's also why `clear` did not work.

You could set up a media query to adjust the `top` position of the button (being that it is relatively positioned), like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) /*Or whenever the button overlaps*/ {
  #header .widget .avia-button-wrap {
      top: 50px !important; 
   }
}
```

But then you'll probably have to adjust some other elements in your header to make everything look okay. But this should get you started!

Comment: can i add the button to the same z-index or remove the index call from the nav?  then what would I do?

Comment: If I was doing this site, I would put the "Register Now" button (or maybe just a simpler link) inside the jumbotron, since it's advertising the same thing as in there, but that's just me *shrug*. You have a lot of things on a lot of different layers so there would be a lot of reorganizing to get it to respond a bit better.